# Trying to add multiple icons to android app

Tags: android, icons, android-manifest

This is the folder with all the icon files

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FmHSDSk.png]

Now in my manifest, I'm not sure how to go about adding these icons.

`android:icon="@drawable/"`

Not sure what to put =/

I've tried putting `@drawable/ic_mood_black_48dp` and it still doesn't work

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dGrx4BJ.png]

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_mood_black_48dp"
```

Those folders are for different resolution screens, and the appropriate png will be automatically shown based on device resolution. The name remains same for all of them, so this should be enough.

Comment: Try cleaning your project once.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio should autocomplete your typing in the manifest as you type it:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_mood_black_48dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to move all the drawable folders outside of the folder 'drawable'.

[image]